# Invalid Charactar in identifier

Tags: python

Invalid Character in identifier. I don't know how to do this converter i'm making.

Ive tried commenting some code out and its not working.

This is the area it is happening in.

```py
 class MetricRobin():
            #568.34 robins in a metric robin
            convertMetric =  input ("What do you want to convert into? ")
            if convertMetric == "pounds":
                count = input ("How many? ")
                count = int (count)
                count = count * 2
                count = count / 568.34
                print (count)
                count = 0
            elif convertMetric == "kilos":
                count = input ("How many? ")
                count = int (count)
                count = count *2.20462262
                count = count *2
                count = count / 568.34
                print (count)
                count = 0

            elif convertMetric == "tons":
                count = input ("How many? ")
                count = int (count)
                count = count * 4000
                count = count / 568.34
                print (count)


                count = 0
```

It just errored it was odd.

Comment: Without declaring a class, your code runs fine on my computer.

Comment: I think having a read through [mcve] would help you help us help you.

Comment: Code run's just fine on my pc